# VueJS Dynamic v-model target

Tags: javascript, vue.js, binding

We are creating a form that has multiple dependencies through several levels on the inputs.  So if `parent1.input1 = 'test'`, then `child1.input1` should equal test. But if `child1.input2 = 'more test'`, then `child1.input3` should equal `'more test'`.

```js
let v = new Vue({
  el:'#someEl',
  data:{
    parentval1:'foo',
    parentVal2:'bar',
    children:[
      {childVal1:'bax', modelAttr:'parentVal1'},
      {childVal2:'bix', modelAttr:'childVal1'},
      {childVal3:'boom', modelAttr:'childVal2'}
    ]
  },
  methods:{
    whichModelField(modelAttr){
      swith (modelAttr){
        case 'parentVal1':
          return xx; //should be bound to some data property if modelAttr === 'parentVal1'
          case 'childVal1':
           return yy; //should be bound to some other data property if modelAttr === 'childVal1'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <p id='parent'>
    <input id="1" placeholder="test" v-model="parentVal1"/>
  </p>
  <p id='child1' v-for="child in children">
    <input  placeholder="test" v-model="whichModelField(child.modelAttr)"/>
    
  </p>
</div>
```

I've figured out how to dynamically bind the `v-model` attr BUT, I cannot figure out how to make it truly dynamic between the context of the current item and the parent data context (context in the loose sense).  IOW, I wish to be able to bind to a data property at any level of the data object, and I can't figure out the syntax to make it so.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/monkeydeus/27wsp5x4/56/)

Comment: Can you update your question to include the vue.js? Also have a look at computed https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html Are you wanting to type something into an input, and if the value = something, set a value?

Comment: The vue code is in the fiddle.  What i'm asking is this: I have 10 rows in a table, each with an input in the first cell.  Some of those inputs need to be bound to one value of a 'parent' data object, and some to a different value in the 'parent'.  Some, on the other hand, need to be bound to other inputs in the same 'child' level.  And this is all based on the value of an attribute in each of those rows in cell 2.  So, I wish to iterate through the rows, and based on the value in cell2 of the row, bind the input in cell accordingly.

Comment: tried to update the snippet to clarify a bit

Comment: v-model is for 2 direction binding, and i don't think you want that the children will update the parent. you should use one direction binding: `:value=""`

Comment: @ZivBen-Or thank you, I'll keep that in mind.  But, OTOH, the spec says we should disable the input on the dependent field, so the data is protected in that regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue is still Javascript - you can access properties with strings

```js
let v = new Vue({
  el:'#someEl',
  data(){
    const self = this
    return {
    parentval1:'foo',
    parentVal2:'bar',
    children:[
      {childVal1:'bax', modelAttr:'parentVal1'},
      {childVal2:'bix', modelAttr:'childVal1'},
      {childVal3:'boom', modelAttr:'childVal2'}
    ],
    whichModelField: {
      get parentVal1(){
           return self.parentval1
      },
      set parentVal1(val){
           self.parentval1 = val
      },
      get childVal1(){
        return self.children[0]['childVal1']
      },
      set childVal1(val){
        self.children[0]['childVal1'] = val
      },
      get childVal2(){
        return self.children[1]['childVal2']
      },
      set childVal2(val){
        self.children[1]['childVal2'] = val
      }
      
    }}
  }
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 0px !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="someEl">
  <p id='parent'>
    <input id="1" placeholder="test" v-model="whichModelField['parentVal1']"/>
  </p>
  <p id='child1' v-for="child in children">
    <input  :placeholder="child.modelAttr" v-model="whichModelField[child.modelAttr]"/>
    
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @monkeydeus like this or should I put some getter,setter proxies to make it more dynamic?

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't considered just a mapping array, I'll do that and see if that works.  Per the fiddle I linked to, it seems like you should be able to do it with 'whichField' kind of processor, but I can't figure out how to make that approach work totally dynamically.  If I hard-code in the $data attribute, I can model bind to the next level up properties, or I can use the equivalent of 'this' to bind to other attributes of the current iteratee, but can't figure out how to switch, on the fly

Comment: That didn't seem to work.  JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/monkeydeus/dpjcsnLy/17/
The fields are just being bound to the lookup val as a string, not the object property the string should point to.

Comment: @monkeydeus - I See getter setter proxies are needed ;) one moment am mobile right now

Comment: thank you for your help.  I'm not sure I have it completely dialed in, but, your work showed me that one of the issues I was facing was having my switch return a string, instead of the actual object property.  I have a rudimentary version working now here: https://jsfiddle.net/monkeydeus/dpjcsnLy/

Comment: @monkeydeus yeah give it a day and let it sink ;)

Comment: I'm actually running into some problems with this approach.  Using getters and setters as you show creates a property on the whichModelField object itself, so I can't set the properties of the data object proper.  If I use a whichField method like in my fiddle, I get the values initially as expected, but, when I try and update one of the bound inputs, I get 'invalid left hand assignment' errors, because the code is trying to assign the element value to whichField(), instead of the property that whichField is supposed to point to.

Comment: @monkeydeus feel free to show me - either here but probably better in a new question - I am sure its some misunderstanding as vue reactivity is based on this approach

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you are looking for:

```js
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        parent:'',
        child:''
    },
    watch:{
        parent: function(value){this.child = value}
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p id='parent'>
    <input id="1" placeholder="test" v-model='parent'/>
  </p>
  <p id='child1'>
    <input id="1" placeholder="test"  v-model='child' :value='parent'/>
    <!-- 1 and parent>input#1 should be bound to same value -->
    <input id="2" placeholder="more test" :value='child'/>
    <!-- 2 and 3 should be bound to same value -->
    <input id="3" placeholder="more test" :value='child'/>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think that is quite it.  I've cleaned up my snippet a little bit.  Basically, every row (child, in children) is going to have an attribute 'modelAttr'.  Depending on the value of 'modelAttr' for that row, the input should be bound to varying data properties.  It may be a property at the top-level (parent) of the data object, or, it may be bound to another attribute of another child.  So, the v-model binding has to be totally dynamic, based on the output of some function, presumably.

Answer (score 0):

I separated between the first child and the others because you want to do 2-way binding only in the parent ant the first child, you don't want that the children will update the parent:

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    parent:'foo',
    child:'bar',
    children:[
      {placeHolder:'bax'},
      {placeHolder:'bix'},
      {placeHolder:'boom'}
    ]
  },
  watch:{
      parent: function(value){debugger; this.child = value}
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input id="1" v-model="parent" placeholder="test"/>
  <input v-model="child"
         :id="0"
         :placeholder="children[0].placeHolder" />

  <input  v-for="i in children.length - 1"
         :value="child"
         :id="i + 1"
         :placeholder="children[i].placeHolder" />
</div>
```